# Периодическое удаление контента из базы

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Есть сгенерированные токены в базе, я хочу что б они были действительны только некое время, как мне реализовать чистку при истекании этого времени?

Comment: Зависит от бэкенд СУБД

Comment: На бекенде mysql  стоит

Comment: Я бы настоятельно рекомендовал разнести "протухание" и чистку. Т.е. в таблицу добавить поле даты актуальности конкретного токена, и в отборе для чистки сравнение текущей даты выполнять именно с ней. Чтобы не хардкодить срок. Заодно появится возможность делать токены с разным временем жизни, а Null будет означать, что токен "вечно живой". Ну а про эвент @Barmaley уже отписАлся. Только, создав его, не забудь включить шедулер, который дефолтно заглушен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишите в MySQL event типа такого:

```
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE EVENT delete_records 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY -- интервал чистки 
COMMENT 'Event deletes old records.' 
DO 
   BEGIN 
      DELETE FROM table1 WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_column) > 7; -- удалить записи старше 1 недели 
   END $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```